# Get first element of a string sublist as a dictionary key with a list of value in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list, dictionary

So I have a list of strings. I need to convert the first part of the string to a key in a dictionary and treat the remaining part as the value. E.G the list is:

```
['We have a nice weekend','Hope you all well']
```

It should return:

```
{'We':['have','a','nice','weekend'],'Hope':['you','all','well']}
```

My attempt is the following:

```
dict1 = {}   
dict1 = {item[0]:item[1:] for item in List1}
return dict1
```

But this give me a result of:

```
{'W':'e have a nice weekend','H':'ope you all well'
```

How to fix it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this.

```
lines=['We have a nice weekend','Hope you all well']
d={}

for line in lines:
    k,*v=line.split()
    d[k]=v
d
# {'We': ['have', 'a', 'nice', 'weekend'], 'Hope': ['you', 'all', 'well']}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
x = ['We have a nice weekend','Hope you all well']
```

then:

```
y = {s[0]:s[1:] for s in (p.split() for p in x)}
```

Then `y` is:

```
{'We': ['have', 'a', 'nice', 'weekend'],
 'Hope': ['you', 'all', 'well']}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following :

```
list1 = ['We have a nice weekend', 'Hope you all well']

# convert a string into list of words separated by a space
list1 = [item.split(' ') for item in list1]
print(list1) # [['We', 'have', 'a', 'nice', 'weekend'], ['Hope', 'you', 'all', 'well']]

dict1 = {item[0]: item[1:] for item in list1}
print(dict1) # {'We': ['have', 'a', 'nice', 'weekend'], 'Hope': ['you', 'all', 'well']}
```

Comment: Thanks but I try another example, it has sublist of '' '' before every value in the dictionary

Answer (score 0):

Replace your 2nd line:

```
dict1 = {item[0]:item[1:] for item in List1}
```

with this:

```
dict1 = {item.split()[0]:' '.join(item.split()[1:]) for item in List1}
```

Comment: This solution needlessly splits each string twice.  It should split each string once.

Comment: @TomKarzes I agree with your comment. Your solution is better way with one split stored in a variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use map to split each string in the list and unpacking to separate the first word from the rest:

```
strings = ['We have a nice weekend','Hope you all well']
result  = { k:v for k,*v in map(str.split,strings) }
```

output:

```
print(result)

{'We': ['have', 'a', 'nice', 'weekend'], 'Hope': ['you', 'all', 'well']}
```